# How Can I set a interval or timeout

Tags: node.js

> Error: 'The write action you are performing on the channel has hit the write rate limit.',

How can I make my loop send at a slower rate. It seems to be sending all at once, although I'm trying to use an increment in a loop one by one.

Its still causing the sendrate to throttle and break. Is using an interval or timeout a good idea. But I'm not sure how I should set it up.

Simple index.js using node.js

```
const autosend = require("discord-autosender")
const fs = require("fs");

    function send(){
    
        var channelID = ""
        var tokenID = ""
    
        const data = fs.readFileSync('mr_robot.txt', 'UTF-8');
        const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
        for (let l_indx = 0; l_indx < lines.length; l_indx++) {
        
            var message = lines[l_indx];
        
            autosend.Post(message, channelID, tokenID)
        }
    
    }
    
    
    send();
```

Mr.Robot.txt

```
A dog of that house shall move me to stand. I
will take the wall of any man or maid of Montague’s.
That shows thee a weak slave, for the weakest
goes to the wall.
’Tis true, and therefore women, being the
weaker vessels, are ever thrust to the wall. Therefore
I will push Montague’s men from the wall and
thrust his maids to the wall.
The quarrel is between our masters and us
their men.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Promise, setTimeout, and async-await to reduce the speed of the loop.

```
function send() {
  var channelID = '';
  var tokenID = '';

  const data = fs.readFileSync('mr_robot.txt', 'UTF-8');
  const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
  const newFun = async () => {
    for (let l_indx = 0; l_indx < lines.length; l_indx++) {
      var message = lines[l_indx];
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      autosend.Post(message, channelID, tokenID);
    }
  };
  newFun();
}

send();
```